# Getting duplicate key error when adding data from table A to table B when data is missing from table B in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am attempting to add data from table A to table B if the data does not currently exist. When I run it as just a select statement everything looks correct. When I add the insert statement I get the error "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.inonhd' with unique index 'PARTLOCA'.". The code I wrote should prevent there from being duplicates. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

```
   insert into inonhd
(fpartno
,fpartrev
,fbinno
,flocation
,fonhand
,fac
,fcudrev)

SELECT INMAST.fpartno
,INMAST.frev
,inmast.fbin1
,inmast.flocate1
,inmast.fonhand
,inmast.fac
,inmast.frev
FROM INMAST
LEFT JOIN INONHD
ON INMAST.FPARTNO + INMAST.FREV = INONHD.FPARTNO + INONHD.FPARTREV
where INMAST.fpartno like 'gs-%'
and inmast.fonhand = '0'
and inonhd.fpartno is null
```

Comment: Looks like one column from INMAST must be getting joined with two columns of INONHD or the reverse .  What all the columns on which the unique index PARTLOCA is defined. We can help you with finding the rows which are causing this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming PartNo and Location being the part of the Unique Index , Use following sql to find rows causing error :

```
select fpartno,flocation,  ct
from 
(SELECT INMAST.fpartno as fpartno  , inmast.flocate1 as flocation
, count(0) ct
FROM INMAST
LEFT JOIN INONHD
ON INMAST.FPARTNO + INMAST.FREV = INONHD.FPARTNO + INONHD.FPARTREV
where INMAST.fpartno like 'gs-%'
and inmast.fonhand = '0'
and inonhd.fpartno is null
group by INMAST.fpartno, inmast.flocate1  ) t
where t.ct > 1
```

Comment: Please use the first answer with MERGE if you are sure, all the rows in the SELECT bellow INSERT are unique.  Else use above SELECT to find the data issue.

Comment: Thank you very much there were 2 duplicates that should not have been there. I will use this code on other tables that should not have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing a join on two columns and matching so probably you need to check for NULL condition on those two columns
is the unique index is a composite key  - FPARTNO and FREV ?

```
and inonhd.fpartno is null and inonhd.FREV is null
```

Also it is better to do with MERGE

```
MERGE INONHD as target
USING ( SELECT INMAST.fpartno
,INMAST.frev
,inmast.fbin1
,inmast.flocate1
,inmast.fonhand
,inmast.fac
,inmast.frev
FROM INMAST ) as source ( frev, fbin1, flocate1, fonhand, fac, frev)
ON fonhand = '0'
   and fpartno is null
   and INMAST.FPARTNO + INMAST.FREV = INONHD.FPARTNO + INONHD.FPARTREV
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (fpartno
,fpartrev
,fbinno
,flocation
,fonhand
,fac
,fcudrev)
 VALUES (source.fpartno
,source.fpartrev
,source.fbinno
,source.flocation
,source.fonhand
,source.fac
,source.fcudrev)
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Rajesh,
also if you are using Merge, you don't need "*and fpartno is null*" filter
and we can apply the other filters inside source sql

```
MERGE INONHD as target
USING ( SELECT INMAST.fpartno
,INMAST.frev
,inmast.fbin1
,inmast.flocate1
,inmast.fonhand
,inmast.fac
,inmast.frev
FROM INMAST 
WHERE INMAST.fpartno like 'gs-%'
and inmast.fonhand = '0') as source ( frev, fbin1, flocate1, fonhand, fac, frev)
ON INMAST.FPARTNO + INMAST.FREV = INONHD.FPARTNO + INONHD.FPARTREV
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND THEN
  INSERT (fpartno
,fpartrev
,fbinno
,flocation
,fonhand
,fac
,fcudrev)
 VALUES (source.fpartno
,source.fpartrev
,source.fbinno
,source.flocation
,source.fonhand
,source.fac
,source.fcudrev)
```